# Cannot compile mysql-python with XCode 4.3/homebrew

Tags: python, mysql, xcode, mysql-python, homebrew

Just installed XCode 4.3, now cannot install mysql-python package. I use OS X Lion 10.7.4, XCode 4.3, homebrew, all installed just few hours ago. Using homebrew'ed python 2.7.3, mysql 5.5.25

Here is the output:

```
(lukasz) ~ > pip install MySQL-python
Downloading/unpacking MySQL-python
Running setup.py egg_info for package MySQL-python

warning: no files found matching 'MANIFEST'
warning: no files found matching 'ChangeLog'
warning: no files found matching 'GPL'
Installing collected packages: MySQL-python
Running setup.py install for MySQL-python
building '_mysql' extension
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.25/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -Qunused-arguments -g
_mysql.c:1: error: bad value (native) for -march= switch
_mysql.c:1: error: bad value (native) for -mtune= switch
error: command '/usr/bin/gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
Complete output from command /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/lukasz/build/MySQL-python/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /var/folders/lv/p8rbhkk559x1337twh8flq0r0000gn/T/pip-Bvu67T-record/install-record.txt:
running install

running build

running build_py

copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7/MySQLdb

running build_ext

building '_mysql' extension

/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments -fwrapv -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.25/include -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.4-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o -Qunused-arguments -g

_mysql.c:1: error: bad value (native) for -march= switch

_mysql.c:1: error: bad value (native) for -mtune= switch

error: command '/usr/bin/gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/Users/lukasz/build/MySQL-python/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --single-version-externally-managed --record /var/folders/lv/p8rbhkk559x1337twh8flq0r0000gn/T/pip-Bvu67T-record/install-record.txt failed with error code 1 in /Users/lukasz/build/MySQL-python
Storing complete log in /Users/lukasz/.pip/pip.log
(lukasz) ~ >
```

Mysql was installed with homebrew without an issue:

```
(lukasz) ~ > brew info mysql
mysql 5.5.25
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/
Depends on: cmake, readline, pidof
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.25 (6382 files, 222M) *
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
https://github.com//homebrew/commits/master/Library/Formula/mysql.rb
```

Is there a way to manually change that *march* flag ?

UPDATE:

Oh, I've also installed *Command Line Tools* (Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads) which apparently creates link for *gcc-4.2*:

```
(lukasz) ~ > which gcc-4.2
/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
(lukasz) ~ > ls -l `which gcc-4.2`
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  12 12 Jun 01:36 /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -> /usr/bin/gcc
(lukasz) ~ > gcc-4.2 --version
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.9.00)
...
```

Comment: Xcode 4.3 does not supply a `gcc-4.2` so you appear to be using a compiler installed from some other source.  What does `gcc-4.2 --version` say?

Comment: @NedDeily, seems like Command Line Tools created that link (Xcode>Preferences>Downloads ...)


    (lukasz) ~ > which gcc-4.2
    /usr/bin/gcc-4.2
    (lukasz) ~ > ls -l `which gcc-4.2`
    lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  12 12 Jun 01:36 /usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -> /usr/bin/gcc
    (lukasz) ~ > gcc-4.2 --version
    i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.9.00)
    ...

Comment: As far as I know, Apple's Command Line Tools do not install a symlink for gcc-4.2 (and I just verified that that has not changed with the just released Xcode 4.3.3 and its Command Line Tools).  But the llvm-gcc that it is linked to is the most recent Apple gcc.  So that's not the problem.  Those flags aren't normally applicable to any Apple compilers; they usually use '-arch '.  It's possible it's being injected by a stray environment variable setting, like CFLAGS or LDFLAGS. Also, check what's recorded in the mysql config by running mysql_config; MySQL-python looks at it.

Answer (score 1):

This is may be somewhat off-topic, but if in the end you'll fail to compile MySQL-python, you can try [PyMySQL](http://www.pymysql.org/) which is pure python mysql client and can be drop-in replacement for MySQL-python. It works quite fast.